# Try and catch scope problems

Tags: java, try-catch

I am having trouble trying to figure out what is suppose to be placed in what scope when handling with try and catch, I have part of my code asks a user to type a file name they want scanned, this is the try and catch statements:

```
try{
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file you wouldlike to scan: ");
    String fileName = scan.nextLine();

    File file = new File(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)                        }                   
    catch( IOException ioe){
                                System.out.println(ioe);
                                System.exit(-1);
                        }
```

When i compile it cannot find the symbol "br" in "line = br.readLine();" //part of the code that scans the file, I am not sure what to place in which scope in the try statement

here is the another(not the whole program) part of the code, i am tested this part with system.in and works fine, not working with filereader though

```
String line;
            int lineCount = 0, wordCount = 0, charCount = 0, palCount = 0;
            int thisLineWords = 0, thisLineChars = 0;
            boolean isPal = true;

            do {
                    try {
                            line = br.readLine();
                    }
                    catch( Exception e ) {
                            break;
                    }

                    if( line == null ) break;


                    if( line.compareTo(".") == 0 ) break;

                    thisLineWords = 0;
                    thisLineChars = line.length() + 1; // count chars
                    isPal = true;

                    //count words
                    boolean inWord = false;
                    for( int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ ) {
                            char ch = line.charAt(i);
                            if( Character.isWhitespace(ch) ) {
                                    if( inWord ) inWord = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                    if( !inWord ) {
                                            inWord = true;
                                            thisLineWords++;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: missing a ); at the end of the new BufferedReader line

Comment: Can you post your code from the try statement to `line = br.readLine();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have stuff like that, what I usually do is the following:

```
 BufferedReader br = null; // here declare the object you want later to use
 try {
      // now the part that could cause the exception
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)); 
 } catch (IOException ioe) {
      // handle exception
 }


 if (br != null) {
    // now use br outside of try/catch block
 }
```

Of course this is applicable to any other objects as well that can cause exceptions and are needed at many places in your program.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the `BufferedReader` will be limited to the try block.  You should place all of the calls to methods on the `BufferedReader` within this block.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of the variable declared in the `try block` ends with its termination. Therefore, the variable `'br'` in your case is not being recognized outside the try block.

What I would suggest, declare the respective variable outside the try block. Check for whether it throws the `FileNotFoundException` in the `try block`. When successfully out of the `try catch block`,

use the respective variable to fetch the respective details that you need.

This is the theoretical logic behind it. Edgar Boda has rightfully displayed the correct coding mechanism to get you to the correct solution. Reading both the answers would help you understand why did you encounter this issue n the first place.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

`catch` block is associated with the `try` block. So your code will be

```
try {
    // read file
    //.....
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

More reading : [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

Move the `br` out of the `try` block scope. The compiler is complaining about can't recognize `br` because after try block scope `br` can not be seen. [Java Scope](http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm)

Comment: @SameerSawla there are syntactical errors in the first posted code. I've pointed that part.

Comment: There are also semantic errors which you haven't addressed. There is also the actual question, which you haven't answered. -1